# Query property against Sum of related model in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

Lets say this model:

```
class Transaction(Model):
    total_cost = DecimalField

class TransactionDetail(Model):
    transaction = ForeignKey(Transaction, related_name="details")
    cost = DecimalField
```

Any Transaction should have the sum of total cost of every TransactionDetail related to it.

How could I query like this ?

```
Transaction.objects.exclude(total_cost = Sum("details__cost"))
```

I am using Django 1.8 and postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the annotation first, then you can filter on it.

```
Transaction.objects.annotate(detail_sum=Sum("details__cost")).exclude(total_cost=F("detail_sum"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but just a detail, had to access the annotation with an F object.

Transaction.objects.annotate(detail_sum=Sum("details__cost")).exclude(total_cost=F("detail_sum"))